# Number of equivalence classes in a set

Tags: linear-algebra

Let **V** be the set of all **nxn** orthogonal and symmetric matrices and define an equivalence relation on **V** by **A~B** iff there exists invertible matix **C** such that **C^-1 A C** = **B**. Since every symmetric matrices have real eigen values every **A** in **V** is similar to a diagonal matrices consisting of eigen values of **A** as diagonal entries. And as every **A** in **V** is orthogonal, ***x1*x2*....*xn**=1 (or -1), and hence if **n-1** of the eigen values are choosen, the remaining one is determined. And hence I concluded that there are infinitely many equivalence classes with respect to this relation.

Is my reasoning correct? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Orthogonal matrices have eigenvalues of modulus one, don't they? And symmetric matrices have real eigenvalues.

Comment: Is that a typo, or did you draw exactly the wrong conclusion from this argument? You have that every such matrix $A \sim D$ for some diagonal matrix $D$ with only $-1$ and $1$ on its diagonal. There are only $2^n$ such matrices. So there can be at most $2^n$ equivalence classes, not infinitely many. (In fact, only one more step is needed to see that there are exactly $n+1$ equivalence classes.)

Comment: @Paul I am not able to see how there are exactly n+1 equivalence classes. Could you clarify it?

Comment: Some diagonal matrices are similar (i.e., congruent under this equivalence relation) to each other. Figure which diagonal matrices with only $1$ and $-1$ on diagonal are similar to each other.